# Why do multiple Oracle JDK binaries differ on different machines when installed from the same RPM?

Tags: linux, java, rpm, java-6, rhel5

We have a number of machines with the Oracle JRE and JDK installed from RPM on our RHEL 5.x system (e.g. java-1.6.0-sun-devel-1.6.0.26-1jpp.1.el5.x86_64 and java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.26-1jpp.1.el5.x86_64 ). I mounted the JVM directory and compared them from Beyond Compare and found a consistent pattern of differences. In, say, the keytool on one machine there is a binary sequence that shows up in several locations in the file. In that same file in the same location on another machine, there is a different binary sequence. Each machine has it's own unique sequence in those locations. The unique binary sequence shows up in all the binary files that differ on a machine.

Is this some sort of watermark or signature? Is this common in ELF binaries installed from an RPM?

This just seemed weird to me, but it is probably just a curiosity. Thanks if you know what's up.

Answer (score 2):

> found a consistent pattern of differences

The RPM post-install script must be doing something; possibly embedding a watermark.

> Is this common in ELF binaries installed from an RPM?

No.